# Displaying Live Time In The Top Of Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I'm currently looking for a way to display the current time/date at the top of my terminal and then have it update, for instance if I use "date +%H%m%s" and then the seconds would update live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
while true; do
    printf '\e]0;%s\a' $(date +%T)
    sleep 1
done &
```

This creates a background shell process which changes the terminal window title bar text to the current time once per second.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, what if I wanted to display the date inside the title bar, as well as the current time?

Comment: Just change the format passed to `date`; you could use `$(date +"%D %T")`, although consult `man date` for the full range of options.